# How to select a single value from a column based on multiple values from another column in SQL/php

Tags: php, mysql, entity-attribute-value

The database is not mine.  The structure is

```
fid| uid | value
 3 |  3  | spain
 3 |  5  | France
 2 |  3  | 45
 6 |  3  | male
 6 |  5  | female
 2 |  5  | 32
```

The field ID is primary key in another table, I'd like to forget about.
Im trying to find all uid that have values 'spain', 'male'

I have the following working.

```
SELECT uid 
FROM DATABASE
WHERE value IN ('spain', 'male') GROUP BY uid HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

The catch is as follows.. How would I select male, spain with value in range of 20-30
(that is males born in spain aged between 20-30?

Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a really messed up table. You are mixing unrelated things in value.

Try:

```
SELECT uid
FROM DATABASE a JOIN
  DATABASE b USING (uid)
WHERE a.value IN ('spain', 'male')
  AND b.value >= 20
  AND b.value <= 30
GROUP BY uid
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Note that I am comparing a string and an integer. You will need to test to see how well that works.

Also, I just put spain and male together, but perhaps they are really unrelated?

Does fid determine the type of value?

Try:

```
SELECT uid
FROM DATABASE country
JOIN DATABASE gender USING (uid)
JOIN DATABASE age USING (uid)
WHERE
  country.fid = 3 AND
  gender.fid = 6 AND
  age.fid = 2 AND
  county.value = 'spain' AND
  gender.value = 'male' AND
  age.value >= 20
  age.value <= 30
GROUP BY uid
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

This code should work more reliably.

Comment: The table is messed up but is contributed by another Drupal Module so there isn't much I can do about it.  fid is a Field ID for a profile field.. It describes the container for the value.  The usage would be SELECT fid FROM DATABASE WHERE uid = 3, then use an INNER JOIN to pull info about the fields along with their value..THAT ALL SAID, your first solution works beautifully and it was the first one I tried, so it's a good day.

Answer (score 1):

Use a self join:

```
SELECT tland.uid
FROM `table` AS tland
INNER JOIN `table` AS tgender ON tland.uid = tgender.uid
INNER JOIN `table` AS tage ON tland.uid = tage.uid
WHERE tland.value = 'spain'
  AND tgender.value = 'male'
  AND 20 <= tage.value AND tage.value <= 30
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
SELECT d1.uid FROM demo d1
INNER JOIN demo d2 ON d2.uid = d1.uid AND d2.fid = 6 AND d2.value = "Male"
INNER JOIN demo d3 ON d3.uid = d1.uid AND d3.fid = 3 AND d3.value = "Spain"
WHERE (d1.fid = 2 AND (d1.value BETWEEN 20 AND 30))
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your syntax as close to what it was as possible, this might work:

```
SELECT uid
FROM database
WHERE value in ('spain', 'male') or convert(value, , SIGNED INTEGER) between 30 and 50
GROUP BY uid HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your fields are mapped as so:

```
fid 3 = country
fid 2 = age
fid 6 = sex
```

You can transform that table into a more logical view (indexed on UID)

```
(SELECT c.uid, c.country, a.age, s.sex FROM
   (SELECT uid, value AS country FROM maintable WHERE fid = 3) c INNER JOIN
   (SELECT uid, value AS age FROM maintable WHERE fid = 2) a ON c.uid = a.uid INNER JOIN
   (SELECT uid, value AS sex FROM maintable WHERE fid = 6) s ON c.uid = s.uid
) as X
```

Once it is inside a view you can then treat your data as a regular table.  I'm assuming you may have more than 3 types of data since fid goes up to 6 on your example.

Assuming you have put that into a view (called X), you can just do:

```
SELECT * FROM X
WHERE age BETWEEN 20 AND 30
   AND country = 'spain'
   AND sex = 'male'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply and thanks also to EVERYONE who replied.  This comment is for all of your responses.  This website is invaluable.  I really get touched when total strangers help me out with a problem.  I only wish I could return the favor as quickly, precicely and as accurately.  If only there was a 'buy me a beer' button!!